# ExecuteGlobal Expected Statement Error VBscript

Tags: vbscript, include

I want to include a VBscript into another VBscript (kinda simulating OO in VBS), found something online and it seems Ok to me. I keep getting an "expected statement"-error on the `ExecuteGlobal` line:

```
Dim scriptLocation

Sub Main
    scriptLocation ="script2.vbs"
    Include(scriptLocation)
End Sub

Sub Include (strFile)
    Dim fsObj : Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim vbsFile : Set vbsFile = fsObj.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1, False)
    Dim myFunctionsStr : myFunctionsStr = vbsFile.ReadAll
    vbsFile.Close
    Set vbsFile = Nothing
    Set fsObj = Nothing
    ExecuteGlobal myFunctionsStr
End Sub
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: What is the content of `myFunctionsStr` before you call `ExecuteGlobal`? Have you tried with something like a `HelloWorld()` function to check that the code is working in principle? Also the above is most definitely not your entire code, as it wouldn't do anything at all.

Comment: the content should be: myFunctionsStr = vbsFile.ReadAll , and it should load another vbs file with a Main sub.

Comment: I can see what it's supposed to do. I was asking what the actual **value** of `strFunctionsStr` is after the file was read. Add a line `WScript.Echo strFunctionsStr` before the `ExecuteGlobal` instruction.

Comment: I recommend [Windows Script Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd79w6c8(v=vs.84).aspx) as method of doing what you want to  do

Answer (score 4):

An error message on an `ExecuteGlobal` line can mean:

1. You succeeded in messing the `ExecuteGlobal` statement up. Surest way: add param list () as you did for the `Include` Sub call
2. The code you loaded into `myFunctionStr` is to blame. If you do chaining/multiple includes this 'feature' of VBScript's error handling makes finding the culprit difficult. Easy way out: run the 'library' files with cscript.

BTW: There is no necessary relation between OOP and including code (libraries/modules).

Comment: Point 2 in this post is probably the solution. If you run the code that you want to include then you probably get the same error message. The ExecuteGlobal command just relays the error message from the included file.

Answer (score 1):

There nothing wrong with the builtin sub `ExecuteGlobal`. Try this:

```
ExecuteGlobal "*"
```

That will bring up *expected statement* error. But the problem, as you can see, lie inside the string. So, just debug your *script2.vbs*.

Comment: P.S. One more friendly advise, do not trust to mass opinion about OOP, there is different OOP concepts and VBS has it's own powerful OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open script2.vbs in HexEditor. If your script encoded in UTF-8, then file contains 0x{ef bb bf} at the start. Method .ReadAll reads just all from file to myFunctionStr, including that 3 bytes. Remove that bytes from string or convert your script2.vbs to ANSI.